# How to stop homegroup sharing folders?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, homegroup

I have homegroup on my PC and laptop, both running Windows 7. I can share the folders and files easily, but the problem is I can't stop sharing the folder. Even I went to computer > manage and stop sharing from there, but inside the homegroup the "stopped" share files are still showing. but now I can't open them because it's showing the network resource is unavailable. But still the folders are showing. How to hide them?

Answer (score 2):

Have you disconnected from your homegroup?

One way you can stop sharing any folders from your homegroup:

1. Go to Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center.
2. In the section "Change your networking settings", click on "Choose homegroup and sharing options".
3. Here, your can choose which library to share, whether to stream media and to leave the homegroup altogether.

Hope this helps!